# Responsive design bug

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I am really desperate about DIV elements positioning bug when trying to create a template for a new responsive layout web design.

The URL is: http://cs.renault-club.cz/responsive_005_bug.php

The problem: when you resize the window to be less than 800px, the "sidebar_right" (online users) DIV element displays not directly under the "obsah" (content) DIV, but bounced under the "sidebar_left" (menu) DIV element.

Please HELP! I spent already 2 hours trying anything, but without any success :(

In less than 500px it works fine, as well bigger than 800px. The current window width is displaying on the top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 2 media queries causing it to push down: if you remove this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px)
#obsah {
    width: 80%;
}
```

and also remove this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px)
#sidebar_right {
    width: 50%; 
}
```

it will work as you see below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

well, between 500 and 800px `#sidebar_right` has a with of 50% - that's too much to fit right of the other elements (seems like this is defined inline, in the `style` tag at the top of that page)

Comment: I was trying to achieve this behavior http://cs.renault-club.cz/responsive_003.php This was a previous version based on css float. It works very nice, but I abandoned it because of fragility. When I use in the "obsah" DIV element (main page content container) some css float and clear: both, then the whole responsive design is broken. So I switched it to display: inline-block DIV elements. But now I realize that by using this method it is impossible to achieve the same behavoir like when using float. It's just behave like a row, row elements. Anyway thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

that's not a bug. it is how the box model works. try:

```
#sidebar_left { float:left; }
```

Comment: xturgorex: thank you very much for your advice. You are true. I already realized it behaves like a row - row elements. Float is nice, works exactly as I expected, but it is too fragile. When I use float and then clear: both; inside the "obsah" DIV element (which is the main content container), responsive design is broken. That's the reason I tried to use display: inline-block elements.